# Issue with Update function in Windows forms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio

This is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update SuperCars set Car=@Car,mph=@mph,price=@price Where(Car=@Car)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mph", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("updated......");
        con.Close();
        Bind();
        Clear();
    }
}
```

When I click on button3 the information in my selected row in th DataGridView1 is inserted into textboxes, so I can change and update them with button4. My problem is when I try to update something in textBox1 , the update doesn't work neither for textBox1, nor for textBox2 and 3. But when i'm updating information in textBox 2 or 3, it works.

Comment: So just to clarify.. If you were to only attempt to change the `Text` in `textbox2` and `textbox3` it works correctly, but when you try `textbox1` as well the `Text` is not updated?  I would suggest setting a `breakpoint` at the `textBox1` line and seeing what occurs.

Comment: I assume that the mistake is in this row, but I don't know how to fix it ..

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update SuperCars set Car=@Car,mph=@mph,price=@price Where(Car=@Car)", con);

Comment: Set the `breakpoint` there and see what the value is.  Otherwise you could use a `Console.WriteLine` and see what the value is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that the column 'Car' is your key but also editable. So when you change the Text in Textbox1 you also change your Key.

So when you change the Text in TextBox1 from "Car1" to "Car2" the SQL Command will look for the line "Car2" to update. If this line doesn't exist the update command does nothing. If this line already exists the wrong line is updated.

You have to store the selected key in a member variable and use it in your update command:

```
private string carKey;  // member variable to store the key

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    carKey = textBox1.Text;  // store the key of the selected car
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update SuperCars set Car=@Car,mph=@mph,price=@price Where(Car=@CarKey)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mph", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarKey", carKey);  // use the stored car key
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("updated......");
    con.Close();
    Bind();
    Clear();
}
```

If you have already an unique key for your car entry you can store and use this instead of the car name to avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks! The key was the problem!